# Zend framework current method to get single row

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

i'm new to zend framework, in this simple function i want to get a single 'post' and then i want to find all the comments in the related table

```
public function getPost($idPost)
{
    $db=  Zend_Registry::get('db');

    $select=$db->select()
            ->from($this->_name, '*')
            ->where("idPost= ".$db->quote($idPost, 'INTEGER'));

    $stmt=$select->query();
    $rowset=$stmt->fetchAll();
    $post=$rowset->current();

    //ora devo aggiungerci i commenti che questo post ha ricevuto
    $comm=$post->findDependentRowset('commenti');

    $ris=array($post, $comm);

    return $ris;

}
```

in my index controller i i simply call this function, but i get this error:

```
Call to a member function current() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\...
```

where's the mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have a few misconceptions about how you're using Zend_Db.

#### 1. You're not using the ORM, just the PDO wrapper

Which means, your queries won't return Zend rowsets and rows and therefore you can't use the methods of you can use on those.

#### 2. The default fetch mode

The default fetch mode of the Zend_Db_Statement fetchAll() method is array, if you want it to return an object (stdClass), change the fetch mode before fetching the data:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
```

#### 3. Using fetchAll() when you actually want one row

If you just want one row, then don't fetch a whole table! With Zend_Db_Statement, use for example:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

or

```
$rowObj = $stmt->fetchObject();
```

... again, that's not a zend row object, just a stdClass instance, but you can do:

```
$rowObj->some_field;
```

on it.

On the other hand, if this is a method in your Post model, it should look something like:

```
public function getPost($idPost)
{
    return $this->getRow($idPost);
}
```

This will return the post, then, if you've setup the table relationships correctly, you can also query for the dependent data or just get all comments with that id separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!!
now i think that i'm using Zend db tables in the wrong way, i have read the official documentation again but i can't understand which paragraph i've missed.

what is the right way to use it?
now i have tried using      
$stmt=$select->query();    
$stmt->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);    
$rowset=$stmt->fetchAll();

but i have the same error...


i could continue working without findparentrow and the other methods, but that will not be the 'zend way', i'm still learning and i think i would be better to start without bad habits

Comment: Again, if you want to use the Zend_Db ORM layer and such methods as current, parentrowset, finddependendrowset, etc. you need to have a model class for your tables first and use Zend_Db_Select. That's where redreggae's answer comes in.

Comment: The way you are doing it you will NOT get a rowset!!! Just an array of rows as if you were querying the database with pure PDO.

Comment: the function above is in my class Application_Model_DbTable_Post wich extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and i created one class for every table i have in my database

Comment: If you did that correctly, you don't need to get the db from the registry, and you should use $this->... to fetch and save stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that unless you [define a table class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.defining) as was previously mentioned you can't uuse the dependent or parent rowsets.

To make your current function work would be best done with two functions, and keep it simple:

```
public function getPost($idPost)
{
    $db= new Zend_Db_Table($this->_name);

    $select=$db->select()
            ->where("idPost= ?", $idPost);
    /*Fetch just the row you want, or use fetchAll() if you need to match return types*/   
    $row = $db->fetchRow($select);

    return $row;

}

public function getComments($table='comments', $id) {

    $db = new Zend_Db_table($table);

    $select = $db->select()->where('post_id = ?', $id)->order('date ASC');
    $rowset = $db->fetchAll($select);

    return $rowset/* or you could return an array ->$rowset->toArray() */

}
```

`Zend_Db_Table` is going to attempt to use the current database adapter, so all you need to do is pass in the tablename.

One more note: you don't need to use any of the `quote()` function when using `select()` it's taken care of.

But it is really important, that if you are going to use Zend_Db, you need to learn about *"Defining table classes"*. At least enough to use them in your own classes.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To get a rowset and dependent rowset you have to use `Zend_Db_Table`.
You only use the `Zend_Db_Adapter` with `Zend_Db_Select`.

Read from [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html).
So you have to define a class which extends from `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`.

Example:

```
class Bugs extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'bugs';
    protected $_primary = 'bug_id';
}
```

To get the `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset` object use:

```
$bugs   = new Bugs();
$rowset = $bugs->fetchAll("bug_status = 'NEW'");
```

To find dependent rowsets you have to define the relation in your table class. Look [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html) how to define relationships.

Comment: i did it, i have written:

     protected $_name = 'post';
     protected $_primary = 'idPost';
    
    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'post' => array(
            'columns' => 'post',
            'refTableClass' => 'post',
            'refColumns' => 'idPost'),
        'autore' => array(
            'columns' => 'autore',
            'refTableClass' => 'utenti',
            'refColumns' => 'idUtenti')
      );

but it doesn't work..I doubt that this is the error..